# Laravel lock table on databse until update finish

Tags: laravel

I have some important table on database such as `payment_settings` and I must be lock this table when we update columns finished, now I want to use `lockForUpdate()` for this table, is correct below code? :

```
$ps = DB::table('payment_settings')->lockForUpdate()->first();
```

is this way correct? lock table until finish update? this action is very important for my customers.

Comment: Use the laravel documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: did the post from @webcodecs answered your question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all work in one transaction, in other words if you want to assure all changes are succesfully persisted or none of them use transactions:

```
DB::transaction(function()
{
    //Do some stuff on DB here ...
});
```

Eventually if you want more controll you can do it in this way:

```
try{
   DB::beginTransaction();
   //Do some stuff on DB here ...
   DB::commit();
}
catch(Exception $e){
   DB::rollback();
}
```

Check laravel docs for more on [Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions)